# Bandwidth limiter for localhost for web development

Tags: bandwidth, web-deployment, bandwidth-throttling

I have XAMPP running on localhost on Windows 7. I was trying to find a way to simulate the bandwidth of dialup and 3G connections.

Is there a current solution which works on a localhost and Windows 7 and is reasonably straight-forward to enable and disable as necessary?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to use Chrome developer tools. 
On network tab, there is feature to throttle bandwidth in different use cases.

Answer (score 1):

[Chales proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) includes a [bandwidth throttle](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/throttling/).

Comment: Too bad it's a non-free application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@sitespeed.io/throttle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sitespeed.io/throttle) - an npm package.

Example:

```sh
# simulate slow 3g connection on localhost
npx @sitespeed.io/throttle 3gslow --localhost

# throttle localhost with roundtrip time of 200ms
npx @sitespeed.io/throttle --rtt 200 --localhost
    
# later when you are done,... stop throttling
npx @sitespeed.io/throttle --stop --localhost
```

Note that `throttle` requires sudo, and will prompt for user login.

Alternatively, `throttle` can be used programmatically in NodeJS.
Example (copied from docs):

```js
const throttle = require('@sitespeed.io/throttle');
// Returns a promise
const options = {up: 360, down: 780, rtt: 200};
await throttle.start(options);
// Do your thing and then stop
await throttle.stop();
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/sitespeedio/throttle) for more options.